# Sampling in a polyhedral complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra, simplicial-complexes

Assume one is given a polyhedral complex $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider picking uniformly at random a $D \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$. Is there way to upper bound the probability that $D$ (a subset of the Boolean hypercube) is *not* a subset of any of the cells of $P$? (feel free to assume any parameters of $P$ that you think you need)